# OutOfMemory using JAI to read image

Tags: java, jai

On certain images, I get an OutOfMemory exception when using JAI. It seems that JAI is attempting to allocate a huge byte[], probably due to some error in the image. Is there any workaround? If not, is there a way to detect the error beforehand? Here is an example:

```
URL bad = new URL("http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/505c5461ecad047a3500002b-772-598/share-of-income-to-labor.png");
RenderedOp op = JAI.create("stream", SeekableStream.wrapInputStream(url, true));
op.createInstance();
```

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNGImage.readChunk(PNGImageDecoder.java:554)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNGImage.(PNGImageDecoder.java:489)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:81)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:120)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.PNGRIF.create(PNGRIF.java:56)
    ... 20 more

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JAI because you're stuck on an old JDK?  The standard JDK 1.6 PNG libraries do not have this problem, at least with the example image that you gave.

e.g (in Clojure, but still using Java API's in JDK 1.6)

```
wget http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/505c5461ecad047a3500002b-772-598/share-of-income-to-labor.png
...
2012-09-21 13:14:54 (370 KB/s) - `share-of-income-to-labor.png.1' saved [64754/64754]

user=> (.exists (java.io.File. "share-of-income-to-labor.png"))
true

user=> (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read (java.io.File. "share-of-income-to-labor.png"))
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

user=> (System/getProperty "java.version")
"1.6.0_35"
```

Comment: no, i use both. first the code tries to use ImageIO and then if it fails it tries JAI. I have found that JAI can successfully read some images that ImageIO seems to be unable to handle. For now I am just going to remove the JAI portion of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to catch the error and report that the image was corrupt.

Comment: this is not really an option for me, i need to either process the image successfully or detect the error beforehand (edited my question to indicate this). thanks.

Comment: In that case, you need to decode the image yourself or use a library which doesn't have this problem. Why is it not an option?

Comment: this is taking place in an app server serving multiple requests. When this happens, the process is unresponsive for at least 5 seconds, which is unacceptable. I hit a similar error using the built in ImageIO classes, but was able to set an "ignoreMetadata" flag to true to bypass the error - my code first tries to use ImageIO to read images and then falls back to JAI if ImageIO was unable to read the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing your heap size gradually. If the error still exists it may be due to a memory leakage. 
see this.
http://jadroider.blogspot.com/2012/07/java-how-to-change-jvm-memory-settings.html